# Spring is not serializing HashMap Attribute

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

First, I am using **Spring MVC**.

I have a "Skill"-modelclass, where I placed the @JsonIgnoreProperties

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"personSkills","berufsgruppes","skills"})
@JsonPropertyOrder({"idSkill", "name", "levelBezeichnung", "skill"})
```

I am using it because there are many-to-many or many-to-one or one-to-many relationships and without this property it causes an StackOverFlowException (Infinite Error). One skill can have many skills, so there is a kind of recursion.

I implemented an Sub-Class for "Skill" named "SkillBean", which has one more attribute "checked" thats just relevant for the application not for database.

```
public class Skill implements java.io.Serializable {

private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<Skill>(0);
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "skill")
public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
    return this.skills;
}
public void setSkills(Set<Skill> skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}

public class SkillBean extends Skill implements Serializable{

public boolean checked;

public SkillBean() {
}

public SkillBean(Skill skill, boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
}
```

Im Using *BeanUtils.copyProperties()* to copy a Skill-Object into a SkillBean-Object. This works fine. I need to reorder the skills because currently I get the lowest Child-Skill first and not its parent. For this, I am trying to reorder objects and trying to build a tree in a list. Every skill has a Set of its children.

```
private ArrayList<SkillBean> formatSkillMap(HashMap<Integer, SkillBean> map) {
    Map<Integer, SkillBean> tempSkills = (Map<Integer, SkillBean>) map.entrySet().stream().filter(p -> p.getValue().getSkill() == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

    ArrayList<SkillBean> list = new ArrayList<SkillBean>(tempSkills.values());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        SkillBean sb = list.get(i);
        tempSkills = (Map<Integer, SkillBean>)     map.entrySet().stream().filter(p -> p.getValue().getSkill() != null)

                .filter(p -> p.getValue().getSkill().getIdSkill() == sb.getIdSkill()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
        Set<Skill> test = new HashSet<Skill>(tempSkills.values());
        list.get(i).setSkills(test);
    }
    return list;
```

**But the list doesnt return the Sub-skillset** Could anyone tell me why the subskills are not serialized? When I return the subset of this parent-skill it their subskills are serialized.

```
0:  {
"idSkill": 34
"name": "Methodik"
"levelBezeichnung": {
    "@id": 1
    "idLevelBezeichnung": 1
    "bezeichnung": "Standard"
    "handler": {}
    "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
}-
"checked": true
}
```

Without reordering it looks sth like this, but the problem is that the skill with id=34 is the parent skill and 9 is the subskill. I want it exactly the other way around. There could be three levels.

```
9: {
"idSkill": 9
"name": "Standards"
"levelBezeichnung": {
    "@id": 1
    "idLevelBezeichnung": 1
    "bezeichnung": "Standard"
    "handler": {}
    "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
}-
"skill": {
    "idSkill": 34
    "name": "Methodik"
    "levelBezeichnung": 1
}-
"checked": true
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Is it an issue with the JPA mapping, the JSON mapping or some part of your code (maybe some part you didn't show us yet)? Did you debug your code to see where it starts to go wrong?

Comment: Btw, the property name "berufsgruppes" makes me shudder ;)

Comment: I debugged it and the listentry for the skill has an hashMap with subkills, but the serialization seems to go wrong and I dont know why or how to find the error. So I dont think it is a part of my code.

So honestly, I dont know whethe it is JPA or JSON mapping.

The model classes are generated by hibernate. I know what you mean :P

Comment: I assume you're loading the skills via JPA and then convert that to some JSON object. Can you check what is loaded by JPA, i.e. whether the subskills are still present? Besides that, some JSON libraries don't like self-references without special handling (at least that's my experience with Jackson) so it might be a problem with your JSON mapping configuration (`@JsonIgnoreProperties({..."skills"})` might be the problem - subskills are set to be ignored).

Comment: I get all skills by DAO via CrudRepository with
`Iterable<Skill> itSkills = skillDAO.findAll();
List<Skill> allSkills = new ArrayList<Skill>();
itSkills.forEach(allSkills::add);`

Comment: I thought it also could be `@JsonIgnoreProperties({..."skills"}`. But when i return the skills without reordering, it works. (See edited json result)

Comment: Did you debug `formatSkillMap()`, especially the intermediate results? It might actually be a matter of `equals()` and `hashCode()` but that's just a guess. Check the results with and without reordering to see if there are any differences besides order.

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4253/8rtdnbe6_png.htm

1) is the list object returned from "formatSkillMap()" and i send this back...
2) are the skills....and i exactly return this!

So there are skill in the map...

What shall i check for "equals()" and "hashCode()"?

Comment: The numbers look out of place, 1) is an id and 2) is the persistent map (and there  is no real information on the content of that map in the image). `equals()` and `hashCode()` might cause the sets and maps not to work as intended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102475/discussion-between-andy-and-thomas).

Comment: Ok, when i remove the "skills" from the @JsonIgnoreProperties it works, with a very simple example, where I create a list with one root node and set a hashmap with 2 nodes as "Subskills"

The (next) problem, one old familiar as said, is then, that I have an infinite recursion caused every skill knows its parent and children-skills.

To solve this now, I ignored the parentskill instead of children sklls, but now I'm missing my parentskill in dataset.

**Is it possible to have parentskill and childrenskill in one object without infinte recursion?**

Comment: Basically it should be possible if you have no cycles in the graph, i.e. at some point there are no further childen. I'm not sure though whether Jackson needs some additional cycle breaking configuration to allow that.

Comment: Btw, does the JSON directly represent the skill tree (assuming it is a tree and not a general graph)? If so you'd only need the children since the container would implicitly be the parent. If you need the parent as well you probably need some custom serialization handler for the parent reference.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I end up with this:

1. Ignore parent of a skill or ignore children of a skill to avoid infinite recursion. **In some case you don't need to ignore one of them. If you have not that much data it could work.** I'am talking about 150 nodes where each node knows its parent/children.
2. I am querying for the path from bottom to top of my lowest skill with a custom sql query.
3. I am putting all my skills on the highest level in a map. That means, I have access to all my skills, cause (as I said) every node knows his children.
4. I am searching in my map from top to bottom and delete all references that I don't need based on the path, which I already got.

The whole code is a bit complex and I'm using recursion to made it less complex. In the end I am not that pleased with this solution because there are many loops in it and so far I am having some trouble with performance-issues.

I need to discover whether it is a database-query problem or a problem caused by the loops.